# if condition is true find max in 3 consecutive rows and report it in a new column - r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

Reproducible example:

```
Label<-c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6)
Value<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,"NC",1,3,2,1,NA)
dat1<-as.data.frame(cbind(Label, Value))
```

The output I am after is a new column "test" that gets the maximum of the column "Value" for each value of the column "Label" when there are 3 consecutives values that are the same and otherwise just report the values of the column "Value".
I do not mind about the missing values at the beggining and at the end, they can stay.

Expected result of the column test: NA, NA, 3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,NC,3,3,3,NA,NA

in excel it was very easy and I coded successfully as follow:
=IF(AND(BN6=BN5,BN6=BN4),X4,Y6)

but in R I cannot.

I tried several methods, the closest to a result is the following:

```
test <-c(NA,NA)
test_tot <-NULL

for(i in 3:length(dat1$Label)){
  test_tot<-c(test_tot, test)
  if( dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i+1]&& dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i+2] ){
    test<-max(as.numeric(c(dat1$Value[i],dat1$Value[i+1],dat1$Value[i+2])))
  }
  if(dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i-1]&& dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i+1]){
    test<-max(as.numeric(c(dat1$Value[i],dat1$Value[i-1],dat1$Value[i+1])))
  }
  if(dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i-1]&& dat1$Label[i]==dat1$Label[i-2]){
    test<-max(as.numeric(c(dat1$Value[i],dat1$Value[i-1],dat1$Value[i-2])))
  }

  else {test<-dat1$Value[i]}


}

test_tot<-c(test_tot,NA,NA)
dat1$test<-test_tot
```

EDIT:
The difficulty apparently is that the column "Value" has character based values. Any solution able to deal with it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that `NC` in `Value` supposed to be `NA`, or did you really want this to be a vector of strings (in which case you need quotation marks around that `NC`)?

Comment: Without the quotation marks, R expects `NC` to be an object. Unless you've already defined an object `NC` in your working environment, running your line that starts `Value <-` as written returns the error `Error: object 'NC' not found`.

Comment: I changed as suggest, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The OP has pointed out that column `Value` may contain character-based values which are important to *identify a specific behaviour happened at a specific time*.

Consequently, the whole vector or column is of type character in R (or factor). The code below has been amended to handle this by extracting numeric values to a separate column, computing the maximum values per group, coercing the result back to character and to copy the character-based values into the result.

The `data.table` solution below

```
Label<-c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6)
Value<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,"NC",1,3,2,1,NA)
Expected <- c(NA, NA, 3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,"NC",3,3,3,NA,NA)
dat1<-data.frame(Label, Value, Expected)

library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# coerce to data.table
setDT(dat1)[
  # create temporary column with only numeric values
  , Value_num := as.numeric(as.character(Value))][
    # create temp cols for group id and group size
    , `:=`(grp = .GRP, N = .N), by = rleid(Label)][
      # for sufficiently large groups compute max values and coerce to char 
      N >= 3, new := as.character(max(Value_num)), by = grp][
        # copy missing values 
        is.na(new), new := as.character(Value)][
          # clean up
          , c("grp", "N", "Value_num") := NULL][]
```

returns the expected result

> ```
>     Label Value Expected new
>  1:     0    NA       NA  NA
>  2:     0    NA       NA  NA
>  3:     1     1        3   3
>  4:     1     2        3   3
>  5:     1     3        3   3
>  6:     2     1        1   1
>  7:     2     2        2   2
>  8:     3     3        3   3
>  9:     3     2        3   3
> 10:     3     1        3   3
> 11:     4    NC       NC  NC
> 12:     5     1        3   3
> 13:     5     3        3   3
> 14:     5     2        3   3
> 15:     6     1       NA   1
> 16:     6    NA       NA  NA
> ```

except for row 15 where I believe the expected result should be `1` if we follow the words of the OP *otherwise just report the values of the column "Value"*

The warning message:

> In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion

can be ignored as it's intended to convert non-numbers to `NA`, here.

Comment: This is a major difference to Excel: R works with vectors/columns not with single cells. I have tried to use `"NC"` but then the whole column is coerced to type character which isn't good to pick a maximum number. However, it would be possible to do this conversion with the final result and have the character string `"NC"` replace `NaN`. BTW: what is the meaning of "NC"? Why is it important?

Comment: It is important to have a character string because it identify a specific behaviour happened at a specific time. In the dataset there will be many of this character based identifiers, and in excel are easy to handle...

Comment: I see. This is important information which should be pointed out in your question. In R, it needs to be treated separately. If such a character based identifier appears in your data set do they always have a separate label? Or, is it possible that there is an label and you have a mix of digits and letters in the `Value` column?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I changed the question. Yes there is a mix of digits and letters in the Value column. +1 for the answer although still does not work in my case.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle character-based values

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr solution. . NOTE: NC was changed to NA

```
Label<-c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6)
Value<-c(NA,NA,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,NA,1,3,2,1,NA)
dat1<-as.data.frame(cbind(Label, Value))

library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Label) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), max_Value = max(Value)) %>%
  mutate(test = if_else(n>=3, max_Value, as.numeric(NA))) %>%
  right_join(dat1, by = "Label") %>%
  mutate(test = if_else(is.na(test), Value, test)) %>%
  select(Label, Value, test)


# # A tibble: 16 × 3
#    Label Value  test
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      0    NA    NA
# 2      0    NA    NA
# 3      1     1     3
# 4      1     2     3
# 5      1     3     3
# 6      2     1     1
# 7      2     2     2
# 8      3     3     3
# 9      3     2     3
# 10     3     1     3
# 11     4    NA    NA
# 12     5     1     3
# 13     5     3     3
# 14     5     2     3
# 15     6     1     1
# 16     6    NA    NA
```

Comment: I tried adding the Character value that I need, NC in this case and the script does not work. Do you know how I could handle this?